SQL - Remove certain text within cell while keeping the other text
I am trying to remove the TMID from the cell as it takes up space and creates noise from the description.
I am looking to go from this (each row here is a single cell)
Transfer CH x9944 to           CH x6664 TMID:T123456789123  111-DEP-0513-Check (2,
Transfer CH x8881 to           CH x5554 TMID:1a2234e56-6dd4-2425-REDEPOSIT4851975
Transfer CH x1111 to           CH x2225 TMID:d558w44h-64tt-6658-DF-0514-Check
To this, each row here still remains a single cell
Transfer CH x9944 to CH x6664 111-DEP-0513-Check (2,
Transfer CH x8881 to CH x5554 REDEPOSIT4851975
Transfer CH x1111 to CH x2225 DF-0514-Check
So in essence removing that TMID, thank you!
I'm not quite sure if a substring_index would work? Or maybe a REPLACE function but my knowledge isn't broad enough on this subject to really know so would appreciate the help!
I've looked at some other posts and I've noticed they have specific text to remove or even exact character count. With this ID of course they are different but they also differ in character length as well so I'm a bit stuck here.

Can you provide statements for CREATE and SELECT so I can test them on DB Fiddle?

You need to consider if you are leaving those values in there and just replacing them for display purpose, or if you want to do an UPDATE with them to remove that from them for good.  If you are new to mysql I wouldn't suggest removing ID tags unless you are sure they aren't used by any other program that generates those logs.

Use REGEX_REPLACE() with case-sensitive collation.

@easleyfixed I'm trying to remove the full TMID for example in the first line I would remove TMID:T123456789123, with the replace function I can do that even if the the characters after "TMID:" are different?

@easleyfixed they are not needed nor are they used so I would like to remove them totally from the cell

Ok I have something that might work, but instead of looping through every column dynamically do you happen to have the column names so it doesn't need to be so long?
(id,name,date,etc)..

Your question was how to remove the TMID, that works with replace, but if you need to remove "TMID and things after it" You will have to build the perfect REGEX statement like Akina mentioned.  That would allow you to select the right data, then we would worry about how to get that selection into a MySQL statment to do the update.  Check this link out to get started -- > https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/#

Of note - the pattern you want to create starts with TMID:    , so thats the easy part, but the hard part is the ID is not a standard format I am seeing letters and numbers, that is going to be a huge paiin to figure out how to tell it to know the end of the value is reached.  If it was all the same type (all numbers, all the same length) its way easier ..   If there are only a few hundred of these maybe you can just manually edit them with MySQL Workbench and just cut them out by hand?

@easleyfixed ah yes my apologies for not being clear! The column title is "description". The TMID is always 18 characters or 21 characters not including the "TMID:"
I noticed my first example has 13 characters which was my own mistake in converting the information to be able to be viewed by the public. My apologies as I am still new

Ok I will type up a real answer after we can confirm this works for you, but try this :
UPDATE YOURTABLENAMEHERE
SET description = REGEXP_REPLACE(description, 'TMID:\S{18,21}', '');

note - please please please backup your data before you do this, if there is an unknown issue we can't roll it back.  Also Set YOURTABLENAME to the table name in question and if there is more than one database use DATABASE.TABLENAME  format

@easleyfixed apologies got caught up with work, unfortunately the solution you gave did not work :(

@easleyfixed Correction! It worked! I just placed it in the wrong section upon initial testing. Thank you so very much for your help!

@easleyfixed hello! sorry for the delay, I think I closed it now correct?

Yes, thank you!  You could technically also "vote" for it with the up arrow if you found the answer userful :)

Normally a simple replace is pretty easy, just replace this thing with that thing.  However, as in this case, sometimes the issue is that there is not a specific standardization of ID values.  There are letters, there are numbers, and the length varies.  How can we find any sort of pattern with this type of situation?
We must consider the things that we do know, such as what characters are we using?  We can see they all start with the same prefix, so we know that is the same, then what is the min and max character count.  But basically after we can work out the perfect regular expression to search for we can combine that with an UPDATE statement to make the changes.
Before attempting to do any mass update like this, you should ALWAYS back your data up because it can be a one way process and too vast to manually repair by hand.
 UPDATE 
    YOURTABLENAMEHERE
 SET
   description = REGEXP_REPLACE(description, 'TMID:\\S{18,21}', '');

The UPDATE command makes the change, replace YOURTABLENAMEHERE with the database.table location of the table in question.  And we are wanting to set a new value for the description column.  Using that Regex designation it will find all the values that start with TMID: and search for the criteria that encompasses all the types that match this pattern.  In this case the length of 18 and 24 characters is used.  And the last part of the replace with the '' means we want to replace that with an Empty value and thus delete it out.
